# Cannot add custom page template to my child theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm running Wordpress 3.3.1.

I'm writing a child theme that modifies the default twentyeleven theme. Everything seems normal, except that when I add a custom page template, it doesn't appear in the add/edit screen (so I can't use it!).

To elaborate on "normal", here's what IS working:
My child theme appears and activates normally.
My CSS code (in style.css) is appearing.
My files from the template hierarchy are working (ex: front-page.php, page.php)

I've read and reread the codex, and my custom page template file ("coming-soon.php") seems to have the correct header:

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name: Coming Soon
 */
```

So why won't it show up under the "Template" drop-down???

I've added custom templates dozens of times and never had this problem. The only possible difference I can think of is that I'm writing a child theme (even though the codex says this shouldn't matter), or perhaps it's a difference in the newest update of WP.

Comment: Have you tried adding this page template to another theme (or even 2011 itself) to see if it's a problem in the theme?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can't duplicate what you're seeing with a clean install of WordPress 3.3.1.  I have a theme with just two files, `style.css`, containing:

```
/*
Theme Name:     stackoverflow-8946077
Template:       twentyeleven
Version:        0.0.1
*/
@import url("../twentyeleven/style.css");
```

and `coming-soon.php`, containing:

```
<?php
 /*
  Template Name: Coming Soon
 */

get_header();
?><h1>Coming Soon</h1><?php
get_footer();
?>
```

the first part of which was copied from your question.

I see the template as expected:

[image: WordPress templates]

The only things I can think of are to double-check:

- the file exists on the server you're running on
- the file's in the child template's directory (though it should work if it's in the `twentyeleven` directory)
- there's no file with the same name in the `twentyeleven` directory, which (I think) would take precedence
- the file name ends in `.php`
- you only have a single space between "Template" and "Name:" (the regex used contains the literal `Template Name:`)

Failing that, the dropdown is populated by the `get_page_templates` function in `wp-admin/includes/theme.php`.  Might be worth sticking some debug code in there to see if the `$templates` variable includes `coming-soon.php`.

Comment: I went through your checklist, and everything was done correctly, but during the process I found the answer to my problem, so I'm awarding the answer to you...

Comment: It turns out that Wordpress had decided my theme was broken, but didn't tell me about it. As I went into the Dashboard>Themes panel, I saw the error about my theme "missing a stylesheet". This is weird because my theme was active and functioning normally at that very time. Solution: I've been developing the site locally using a style.LESS file (which my development server compiles into .css on the fly.) I must have changed it form .css to .less AFTER activating it, and somehow that wasn't a problem until now.

Comment: Ah cool; glad you found the answer, even if it wasn't something I suggested.  Thanks for accepting my answer though - appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread. But if anyone is looking for solutions now, it may be the issue in WP 4.9. More details: [Templates not working properly](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42573)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out man!! Bumping the version worked for me

Answer (score 1):

In my situation, it ended up being the file permissions. I set it to 755 or whatever the standard WP permission is (in regards to security) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Mine also ended up being the file permissions.

I set it to 777, and it worked like a charm!

Comment: Be careful with 777. It probably won't matter in your case but you wouldn't want to do that to entire directories