# Wordpress - no themes

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have installed a fresh copy of wordpress on a windows XAMPP server. I configured the wp-config file and ran the install script. All is ok, and I am able to view my new wordpress site and login to admin area.

However - when I go to Appearance->themes - the current theme is set to TwentyTwelve and in the lower section the "Available Themes" does not show ANY themes.

After this I copied a new theme to the themes folder (which was working on a WP install on my test server at work) and that doesn't show up either.

Can anyone tell me how to make the other default theme (TwentyEleven) and more importantly my own built themes, appear as being available?

Thanks :)

Comment: Every theme in that folder mast have `style.css` with some information like `Theme Name`, `Description` etc as comments at the top and this `style.css` should be placed in the root folder of the theme folder.

Comment: May not be the case for you, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946077/cannot-add-custom-page-template-to-my-child-theme) saw weird theme behaviour solved by updating file permissions

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the theme folder permissions to 777

Answer (score 0):

`style.css` is very important for a theme.
You should check either style.css exists or not. 
If No, try install wordpress again. 
If Yes, then there might be the issue of File Permissions.

Set file permissions from below.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions